# Javascript: Is it possible to set different font sizes for different texts in a 2D canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas

Afaik, you can only set the font for the WHOLE canvas.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");  
ctx.font = "30px Arial"
```

I would like lets say, text1 to be "30px Arial" and text2 to be "10px Arial". Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, its is possible:

```
//first text
ctx.font = "30px Arial";
ctx.fillText("Hello World",10,50);
//second text
ctx.font = "20px Arial";
ctx.fillText("Bell World",50,100);
```

Comment: In my canvas, it's overwriting with previous one!

Comment: Maybe you need redraw the text, because the canvas is like an image. Try create a fiddle with code example to clarify your problem.

Comment: Hey, Thank you. I was running loop for multiple frames that's why the problem has occurred.  your example actually works.